# How to store existing string secretly in ios swift app

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

I am working on ios application,which contains some files which are AES-128 encrypted,so for decrypting these files, I am using some third party libraries like cryptoswift,right now in swift code only i am writing my own logic to decrypt data using keys,but i want to store these keys securely,for android i had written my logic in native library,here what is the best way to secure my secret key

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 100 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: You can obfuscate your key storage in your code; store it split into multiple pieces, store it in a form that requires some mathematical operations to recover the key etc. this will make it more difficult for an attacker to extract your key but there is little you can do to protect against a determined attacker since ultimately the key is there somewhere.

Comment: @Paulw11 Defending against the owner is essentially impossible but defending against someone else with physical possession relies on the quality of the lock code, a locked device is secure against virtually any attacker.

Comment: @zaph as I understand the question, the files will be encrypted and included in the app bundle. Since the attacker can download the app from the store, the device owner and the attacker are one and the same. If the files are generated on the device and the intention is to protect the files from "others", then yes you could generate a randommkey and store it in the keychain, but it is even simpler to use the file system encryption that is built into iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 Agree. If the need is to include a file and protect it against all users that is a DRM issue and there is no 100% solution. Yet the OP accepted a keychain solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [iOS Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) to store the keys securly.

There are several libraries implemented in Swift which provide easy access to the key chain. See here: https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#keychain

Comment: how to add my key to keychain,if i write that logic in swift anybody can see that key

Comment: That depends on the architecture of your key generating mechanism... If you create the key on the device for example you never have to write the key into the swift code.
If you have pregenerated keys you must provide them with the app and ask the user for a password for example.

Comment: @parker Define "anybody"? The device owner can since they have possession and full control. The same applies to devices without a lock code. Securing from the user requires DRM, not just encryption.

Comment: @parker What does writing the code in Swift have to do with security?

Comment: i am having static key so where should i add,using that static key only i will decrypt data using cryptoswift library

Comment: @zaph suppose if i use swiftkeychainwrapper library i need to write code like this let saveSuccessful: Bool = customKeychainWrapperInstance.set("Some String", forKey: "myKey")

let retrievedString: String? = customKeychainWrapperInstance.string(forKey: "myKey")

  so if anybody do reverse engineering my app they can see my key

Comment: 1. An attacker will not have access to your Swift source code. 2. Create a key composed of random bytes, use `SecRandomCopyBytes`. Save that key in the keychain, When you need the key recover from the keychain and use it. Every device will have a different key.

Comment: An attacker will not have static access to the compiled code either, for iOS the code is encrypted with Apple's key and is only decrypted by the OS when it is run so the only attack is an attack on the executing code. Such an attack is possible but difficult.

Answer (score 0):

For storing sensitive information you should use the Keychain always.You can use the following sample code posted by apple to know in detail [Generic Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html).Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: See the discussion under it. Wise conclusion: Perhaps the best answer is "don't bother, put the key in the code", there is a large work factor to obtain the key.

If you store a secret token within the app there's a risk it would be easily recoverable as simple string. You can read more about it at [Reverse Engineering iOS Apps](https://www.whitehack.com.au/reverse-engineering-ios-apps/).

You can't prevent it totally, but you can obscure password data by splitting password into smaller chunks, keep them apart in the code, and use some dumb-decryption algorithm to retrieve final form, like this:

```
func crypt(string: String) -> [UInt32] {
    return string.unicodeScalars.enumerated().map { index, char in
        return char.value + UInt32(index)
    }
}

func decrypt(chars: [UInt32]) -> String {
    return chars.enumerated().map { (index, char) -> String in
        let s = UnicodeScalar(char - UInt32(index))!
        return "\(Character(s))"
    }.joined()
}

let clearPassword = "Acb,321"
let cryptedChars = crypt(string: clearPassword)
let decrypted = decrypt(chars: cryptedChars)

let c1: UInt32 = 65
let c2: UInt32 = 100
let c3: UInt32 = 100
let c4: UInt32 = 47
let c5: UInt32 = 55
let c6: UInt32 = 55
let c7: UInt32 = 55

let decryptedScattered = decrypt(chars: [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7])
```

Not perfect, but should be enough for simple attacks, and more advanced ones would be probably too expensive to proceed.

Comment: You were doing fine until "use some dumb-decryption algorithm".

Comment: @zaph And could you elaborate more, why so? In which other way you suggest to store a token inside a binary? Keychain is available only in runtime, not compilation time. A random key you suggested above is not solving the problem at all, when you have files already encrypted with given secret.

Comment: Why use "some dumb-decryption algorithm" when AES is available? The word "dumb" says it all.

Comment: @zaph Do you suggest to use AES to encrypt an AES access key to the files? Then how would you store the key to the AES then? If in plain text it is as "dumb" as "dumb" algorithm. If somehow different – please explain – I'm really curious, I faced such problem before and I didn't find anything better than "dumb" solution.

Comment: To be clear: using "some dumb-decryption algorithm" is dumb.  An attacker will install a runtime attack and see the key at the point it is used. For iOS the code is encrypted with Apple's key and is only decrypted by the OS when it is run so the only attack is an attack on the executing code. Perhaps the best answer is "don't bother, put the key in the code", there is a large work factor to obtain the key.

Comment: @zaph That's what I expected as a good answer. Thanks. I wasn't sure about encrypted binaries, I thought they were only signed. As if I remember correctly when I was playing with it some time ago (rather some long than some short) it was extractable easily with `strings` without any decryption, but I might be wrong. Runtime is a bit harder than that, so I mentioned it as "good enough" simple attacks, but of course far from being perfect. Updating answer.